# Ctrl+s should save post content when input field is in focus

Tags: feature-request

Instead of opening the save page dialogue, I think cmd+s should save the post content when the input field is in focus.

It's a force of habit to do this when I'm writing code, so I'm constantly pressing the save command when I'm writing code on SO. The save dialogue hangs the browser for a couple of seconds, and then I have to close it.

Note that this won't completely override the default cmd+s browser function. It will only override it when an input field is in focus.

Post contents could be saved to local storage or something. This would allow users to close the page and recover lost post content.

Comment: +1 - like WordPress.

Comment: I believe you mean ⌘+s

Comment: We already save drafts of questions and answers (but not comments). Without a shortcut to trigger it, though.

Comment: I thought you might - and that's awesome. I approve of that feature. But I think it would still be cool to throw in an event.preventDefault on ⌘/ctrl+s (@jmac, you happy? :p). You have no idea how much time it would save me. I use SO on a daily basis, but I spend way more time writing code. I don't think the instinctual save command is going to go away any time soon.

Comment: @AnnaLear unfortunately, that doesn't always work, and there isn't any indication when it fails or when was the last push. I have already lost a draft this way.

Comment: Out of curiousity, would Alt-S be acceptable? (like JIRA)

Comment: No. The reason I suggested this feature is because I press cmd+s out of habit when I write code, and it brings up the save page dialogue.